# Node.js - "Unknown file extension .ts" on npm package

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I'm trying to publish my first package on npm. The package is an CLI to install Eslint with other plugins easily.

The problem I'm facing is the error:

> Unknown file extension ".ts"

I've been reading similar topics but none of the solutions worked for me. Maybe because the nature of the project may be different.
The project is written in **Typescript**, and I'm using **ts-node** to handle it.

The code runs perfectly when I execute it with "npm start [script]", but for reasons of publishing it on NPM, I have to test it in another project. To do so, I've linked it with "npm link" and then in the test project "npm link auto-eslint" (the name of the package).
When I try to run it in this test project just executing "auto-eslint", is when I recive the error.

Here is the package.json:

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "bin": "./src/index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "ts-standard",
    "start": "node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node --loader ts-node/esm src/index.ts",
    "auto-eslint": "auto-eslint"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "linter",
    "eslint"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.4.5",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "eslint": "^8.46.0",
    "ts-standard": "^12.0.2",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@clack/prompts": "^0.6.3",
    "picocolors": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/semver": "^7.5.0"
  }
}
```

And tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ESNext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true
  },
  "lib": ["esnext"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
}
```

The test project is just contains and empty index.ts and a default package.json, without any dependecy or extra configuration.

Here is the repository if you want to look deeper: https://github.com/baccci/auto-eslint

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the error might happen when you try to use it as a CLI tool. You might want to transpile your TS code to JS and then point the `bin` property to that file instead. Easiest way to build/bundle would be to use [tusp](https://tsup.egoist.dev/)

Comment: Your tsconfig outdir is `dist` so your package.json should probably be `"bin": "./dist/index.js"`

Comment: Yes, I've solved it build it with tsc and poiting "bin" to it, thank you!